# FileInputStream read multiple lines inside while loop due to if condition

Tags: java, while-loop, io

Actually this is my code :

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("blablbal") {
         // **take the next five line and put them inside string or something** 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to take the next five lines and put them inside string object?

And if there is another occurrence of the condition within these 5 lines how to treat that case?

Any idea?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i can t find how the while loop  iterate line by line can t find how to take the next fex lines any suggestion ? @ glenebob

Comment: You can try a loop within the if {} block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with below code:-

```
          String[] lines = new String[20];
          //if you want to store more lines increase the size of the array
          int j = 0;
          //manage below while loop condition j < 20 based on array size and change the 
          //number from 20 to that number. For example if array size 50 make j < 50
          while (sc.hasNextLine() && j < 20) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                if(line.contains("blablbal") {
                   int i = 0;
                   while(sc.hasNextLine() && i < 5){
                     line = sc.nextLine();
                     if(line.contains("blablbal") {
                        continue;
                     }
                     lines[j++] = line;
                     i++;
                     if ( j >= 20 )//change this according to the size of array as well
                        break;
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: thank you for your help i  don t wanna add the other condition inside first loop cause im not sure how will must be the size of lines oject

Comment: No worry. Just remove  the condition from out loop. It will still work.

Comment: @ Abhijit Pritam and if there is another occurence of the condition within these 5 lines hwo to treat that case

Comment: @patoCapongo93, I have modified my answer. Check what that if condition will do?

Comment: :i have add if i>=4 for(string line:lines) sysout(line)) ==> just before the ending of the big if ==> it show me the first two lines and nullpointer exception any idea ! @Abhijit Pritam

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can. Actually the only thing you have to do is to invoke a method *doWhatYouWantToDoInCaseOfYourDesire*

Do you want to read 5 lines below the given? ok - just create a method that contains a check for a your's condition, contains a counter inside and loop inthere.
But the question is what are you going to do if there is another occurence of your condition within these 5 lines? 
I believe it's not enough description for this case

Comment: i have edited my question yes i should handle that case  too  @Yuriy Tsarkov